# I'm new to pointer to pointer concept as I'm learning how to use the incrementing in pointer to pointer

Tags: c, dereference, pointer-arithmetic, post-increment

Why I'm getting some garbage value when I increment like this **pptr++ but not for *ptr++? Can anyone help me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int array[] ={9,1,2,3,4}; 

    int *ptr = array;
    int **pptr = &ptr;


    **pptr++;
    printf("%d",**pptr );

    *ptr++;
    printf("%d",*ptr );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you take some paper and a pencil, and draw out the array as a rectangle, which you divide into five squares. The first square is `array[0]` and the last `array[4]`. Then draw another square for `ptr` and yet another for `pptr`. Then draw arrows from `pptr` to `ptr`, and from `ptr` to `array[0]`. That's how the pointers works really.

Comment: As for what happens with the `++` that's explained by [the answer by MiceCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67419310/440558). With this information, erase and redraw the corresponding arrow on your paper when you do the increment. Notice how `ptr`now is pointing to `arrow[1]` instead on your piece of paper? And notice how `pptr` no longer points to anywhere valid.

Comment: `**pptr++;` doesn't make any sense so that would be why. There are few cases where you actually need to use pointer to pointers and this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

`**pptr++;` and `*ptr++;` are incrementing the pointer, not what is pointed at by them.

`pptr` is pointing at `ptr`, which can be seen as one-element array. Incrementing `pptr` will move the pointer to out-of-range and disallow dereferencing that.

`ptr` is pointing at the first element of the 5-element array `array`. Incrementing `ptr` will move the pointer to point at the 2nd element. You are still allowed to dereference this.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `pptr` points to the pointer (object) `ptr` due to these declaration.

```
int *ptr = array;
int **pptr = &ptr;
```

This expression

```
**pptr++;
```

may be rewritten just like

```
pptr++;
```

because applying the dereferencing operator does not have an effect.

So now the pointer after incrementing `pptr` points to the memory beyond the pointer `ptr`  and dereferencing it in the following statement

```
printf("%d",**pptr );
```

results in undefined behavior.

Instead of these two statements

```
**pptr++;
printf("%d",**pptr );
```

you could write just one statement

```
printf("%d",**pptr++ );
```

and the output will be

```
9
```

though post-incrementing the pointer does not make a sense.

As for these statements

```
*ptr++;
printf("%d",*ptr );
```

then again it may be rewritten like

```
ptr++;
printf("%d",*ptr );
```

because dereferencing the pointer in this expression `*ptr++` does not have an effect.

As the pointer `ptr` points to the first element of the array `array` then after incrementing it it points to the second element of the array.

Thus this call

```
printf("%d",*ptr );
```

outputs

```
1
```

To make it more clear you may consider this declaration

```
int **pptr = &ptr;
```

as a declaration of a pointer that points to the first element of an array with only single element. Thus incrementing the pointer results that the pointer will point beyond the array with a single element.

Unlike the pointer `pptr` the pointer `ptr` points to the first element of an array that contains more than one element. So after incrementing the pointer it will point to a valid object: the second element of the array.

That is the difference.